# How do I conduct data analysis on Stellar?

Tags: data

I work as a data scientist for a tech company. I'd love to to run some ML models by pulling data from the blockchain. How would I pull data in a tabular format?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I imagine that in the context of ML you're looking at analyzing historical data. Easiest for that is to ingest the time range you're looking for using [Horizon](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/horizon) and play with [effects](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/effects-all.html). You could also be querying Horizon's database directly and bypass the APIs but it may make your code more tightly coupled with Horizon.
For Horizon to have the right data you will need to run an instance, join the network and let it catch up by replaying history.